# Vaadin CssLayout: Is it possible to update the style/CSS of a child component?

Tags: vaadin

I use Vaadin CssLayout and override the

```
String getCss(Component c)
```

method to define styles for the child components, which works fine.

But how can I change the style for a child? And trigger an update on the client side?

Comment: With 'child', what do you actually mean? Is it a sub class of `CssLayout` or is it just a child in the HTML DOM?

Comment: @Thibstars i mean those components that i add to the layout with `addComponent`.

Comment: you could just use `addStyleName` or `setStyleName` on those components you add to the layout. Apply styling to style names in your theme.

Comment: @Thibstars I am aware of that (and I wouldn't need CssLayout for that). I am interested in changing the style of an element, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible solution:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("document.getElementById('" + vaadinComponent.getId() + "').style.background = 'green';");
```